# Grouping values in Pyspark

Tags: lambda, pyspark

I need help with the following.
Suppose I have a data frame like the one below. I'm looking to generate an appendix of the dom and attribute columns based on the order of the "rank" column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import first
l =[( 1    ,'A', 10, 'size' ),
( 2        , 'B', 20, 'height' ),
( 3        , 'C', 30, 'weigth' )]

df = spark.createDataFrame(l, ['rank','dom', 'value', 'attribute'])

+----+---+-----+---------+
|rank|dom|value|attribute|
+----+---+-----+---------+
|   1|  A|   10|     size|
|   2|  B|   20|   height|
|   3|  C|   30|   weigth|
+---+---+-----+---------+
```

Final desired output:

```
+----+-------+---------+--------------------+
|rank|    dom|avg_value|           attribute|
+----+-------+---------+--------------------+
|   1|      A|       10|                size|
|   2|    A,B|       20|        size, height|
|   3|  A,B,C|       30|size, height, weigth|
+----+-------+---------+--------------------+
```

The idea is that avg_price is an average grouped by the new attribute combination.

Comment: Shouldn't the row with rank two contain an average value of 15 and the row with rank 3 an average value of 20?

Comment: Imagine that real data contains more than 2MM of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a window functionality and collect previous attribute values.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

l =[( 1    ,'A', 10, 'size' ),
( 2        , 'B', 20, 'height' ),
( 3        , 'C', 30, 'weigth' )]

df = spark.createDataFrame(l, ['rank','dom', 'value', 'attribute'])

windowSpec = Window().orderBy('rank').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
df = df.withColumn('attribute',f.collect_list(f.col('attribute')).over(windowSpec))
df.show()
```

Output>

```
+----+---+-----+--------------------+
|rank|dom|value|           attribute|
+----+---+-----+--------------------+
|   1|  A|   10|              [size]|
|   2|  B|   20|      [size, height]|
|   3|  C|   30|[size, height, we...|
+----+---+-----+--------------------+
```

If you have different groups of data, u can create partitioned window

```
windowSpec = Window().partitionBy(PARTITION_COLUMN).orderBy('rank').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
```

Comment: Perfect, I will test this solution with real data (containing more than 2000MM of rows) and different groups of data. So the "partitionBy" will definitely be useful. Thank you!